# Saving data into MongoDb returns an ObjectParameterError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am practicing on saving data into MongoDb using Node.js.

I have set up Express server and created a Mongoose model but when I try to save some data through Postman it keeps returning an ObjectParameterError.

Mongoose version is 5.5.13 and Express version is 4.17.1.

Connecting to MongoDb through Mongoose has no problem since it does not return any errors at least, but the problem is when I am trying to save some data with a post request.

Here is my post request from my server.js:

```
router.post("/create_contact", (req, res) => {
  const { name, number } = req.body;

  let contact = new ContactData(name, number);

  contact.save((error, contact) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.error(error);
    }

    return res.json(contact);
  });
});
```

And my data.js that defines the Mongoose Schema and model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  number: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("ContactData", ContactSchema);
```

As you can see, it only has 2 types of data in it: name and number.

I want to save this simple contact data into local MongoDb but I am getting this one Error:

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got John Doe
    at new ObjectParameterError (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\objectParameter.js:25:11)
    at model.Document (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:73:11)
    at model.Model (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:96:12)
    at new model (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4580:15)
    at router.post (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\server.js:28:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\LearnReact\db\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In:

```
const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  number: Number
});
```

You forgot to add `new` that is:  `new mongoose.Schema({`

And

> { ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object Mostly caused by parameters passed to mongoose that is NOT an object.

in `let contact = new ContactData(name, number)` , modify from `(name,number)` to `({name:name, number:number})` or just `({name, number})` as they have the same name.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention that I have tried that too. Still get the same error. Or am I testing it in a wrong way? I am sending a post request through Postman, putting data { "name": "John Doe", "number": "1413415" } within body-raw tab.

Comment: @Auclown { ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object Mostly caused by parameters passed to mongoose that is NOT an object. try searching your create methods or parameters you sent to them and check if they're missing {} curly braces.

Comment: @Auclown in ```let contact = new ContactData(name, number)``` , modify from ```(name,number)``` to ```({name:name, number:number})``` or just ```({name, number})``` as they have the same name. Let me know.

Comment: @Auclown I'm happy for you, really) And could you please accept my answer, if helped you.

Comment: Done! Have a great day :D

Answer (score 8):

You are passing parameteres, where you need to send `object` to save in mongo db

Try this,

```
let contact = new ContactData({name, number});
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the name and number as an object
like this `let contact = new ContactData({name, number});`

Answer (score 4):

Your Error `ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got John Doe`

It says all you are not passing it an object.

Edit this line in your code

```
let contact = new ContactData(name, number);
```

Pass your values as an object like this below:

```
let contact = new ContactData({name, number});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I dig up this question, but I think you forget to send your POST request in JSON format.